# Adjusting the x-Axis and Bins when Making a Histogram with Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I,n new to histograms in ggplot2 and feel like I'm missing something obvious. Using the the data below, I'm trying to create a simple histogram. All I want to do is have the x-axis count by 5, so 0-5-10-15-20-25-30...etc...100. So the bins will divide the age group by 5. I'm thinking maybe I have to set boundaries or something? I'm not sure why the example below creates some bars wider than others, and why the bars don't line up properly on the x-axis.

I tried to find similar questions that have been asked previously but I'm still confused,especially between "break=" and "binwidth" and boundaries, etc.

I would prefer an answer that uses ggplot 2.0.

```
 Age<-c(18,82,65,89,10,44,46,23,10,15,22,33,34,30,50,60)
 Sex<-c("M","F","F","M","F","M","F","M","F","M","F","M","F","F","F","M")
 Df<-data.frame(Sex,Age)

 ggplot(Df,aes(Age))+geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,100,by=10),aes  (fill=..count..))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`binwidth` controls the width of each bin while `bins` specifies the number of bins and ggplot works it out.

Depending on how much control you want over your age buckets this may do the job:

```
ggplot(Df, aes(Age)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 5)
```

Edit: for closer control of the breaks experiment with:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 5))
```

To label the actual spans, not the middle of the bar, which is what you need for something like an age histogram, use something like this:

```
ggplot(Df, aes(Age)) +
geom_histogram(
    breaks = seq(10, 90, by = 10), 
    aes(fill = ..count..,
    colour = "black")) + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 90, by=10))
```

Comment: I suppose I'm confused about what exactly "binwidth" does. For the above example, I basically want the range from 10 to 90 (based on the age groups in the example) on the x-axis, in bins of 10, so there would be eight bars. I think I'm missing a key point when making the histogram since I can't seem to create this simple layout...

Comment: So basically the first bar (10-20) would have a count of 4, and the second bar would have to actually be from 21-30, and have a count of 3, etc. So I guess there is something to also do with setting boundaries to get an accurate histogram?

Comment: see edit for a suggestion on controlling the breaks precisely,

Comment: This code produced what I was looking for - ggplot(Df, aes(Age)) + geom_histogram(breaks=seq(10,90,by=10),aes(fill=..count..,colour="black"))+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 90,by=10))

Comment: Binwidth doesn't seem to help, so I used "Breaks", but the scale_x_continuous was what I needed!

Answer (score 5):

Is this along the lines what you are looking for?

```
Df$cut <- cut(Df$Age, seq(0,100,by=5))
ggplot(Df,aes(cut))+geom_histogram(stat= "count", aes(fill = ..count..))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I want. Please see the comment I wrote for the other answer above. I want something similar to the above, but not pre-binned if possible?

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this within geom_histogram, or using stat_bin?